# Splitting of values in a JSON array

Tags: c#, json.net

I have my json `["[\"~:bbl:P5085\",\"~:cosco:NoTag\"]"]` coming in

> options.Type1.Values()

I am trying to keep only the values coming with bbl so from above I want to keep P5085 and remove all, there can be multiple bbl values in here and I need to keep all. I tried the below code but its not working. The splitting gives me

> **P5085","~:cosco**

I dont understand what wrong am i doing in below code. Can someone provide the fix here?

```
private void InitializePayload(JsonTranslatorOptions options)
        {
            _payload.Add("ubsub:attributes", _attributes);
            _payload.Add("ubsub:relations", _relations);
            JArray newType = new JArray();
            foreach (JValue elem in options.Type1.Values())
            {
                if (elem.ToString().Contains("rdl"))
                {
                    string val = elem.ToString().Split(":")[1];
                    newType.Add(val);
                }                   
               
            }           
            _payload.Add("ubsub:type", newType);
        }
```

Comment: `{["~:bbl:P5085","~:cosco:NoTag"]}` isn't valid JSON. You can't place an array directly in an object without using it as the value of a property.

Comment: I would just deserialize the json with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TYPE>(JsonObj)

Comment: @micahkimel that's not JSON. It can't be deserialized

Comment: @gunr2171 i have edited the json, i mistakenly put {} instead of []. check teh jsonm again

Comment: That string isn't JSON. It's not just that an object can't contain raw arrays. The array contains just strings separated by `:`,  not objects with properties and values. This string doesn't follow any JSON conventions

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint that's still not JSON. Now you have an array containing a single string value, whose contents aren't JSON. Where did you get that string from? Does the `SharePoint` in your user name have anything to do with the source?

Comment: ?? thats an array type object . i just checked with online json validator and it passes there as well

Comment: Because all you have is an array with a single string value that has no meaning in JSON.

Comment: You've just added some quote marks which weren't there before in this version, and changed it to an array. That's the difference. So now you have an array with one string in it. Please don't try and make out like it's been valid all along, when you've just [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70710952/revisions). Just be honest and say you've changed it from what you showed before, and it's now valid.

Comment: Is there anything you can do to make that structure nicer before you receive it? Because it's pretty messy. Where does it come from?

Comment: `~:bbl:P5085` isn't a valid JSON fragment. Even if you extracted the single string value from the array, you'd only be able to parse it as two strings, none of which could be parsed as JSON. Again, where did this string come from?

Comment: I am honest here, I am getting this structure from an api call, i am debugging right away and the initial structure i get from api call for this key is like this 

"bbf:type": [
      "[\"~:bbl:P5085\",\"~:cosco:NoTag\"]"
    ]

Comment: Is that what raw SharePoint field data looks now? SharePoint doesn't store data as JSON, it uses its own quirky encoding to store multiple values in a single table field. Back in 2003 when SharePoint migrated from Exchange storage to SQL, there was no support for either JSON (that came in 2016) or XML (that came in 2005), so they created their own quirky and slow way of encoding arbitrary fields and types in a single row. Instead of using a horrible EAV schema they used an equally horrible schema where each column represents a different field type, with all the type's values in a single field

Comment: `I am getting this structure from an api call` what API call? If it's SharePoint, use the SP clients instead of trying to make sense of the internal storage format

Comment: no its not a SP call, its a different application all together and they have this way of defining namespaces in json

Comment: That's not JSON. You won't be able to find any solution if you insist on calling this JSON. It's not. What application is it? Doesn't it have a client? If not, you have to treat everything below the top level as a custom format. `JArray.Parse` will get you the single string. After that, assuming the string always contains a JSON array, another `JArray.Parse` will get you the values. After that, assuming there are no values with colons, you can use `String.Split(":")` to get the parts. Then you have to guess what the parts mean. Too many assumptions

Comment: If you can't find a client you'll have to find the actual specification of that format. You can't assume there are always two nested arrays, or that no value will have colons. What if one does? How would that be encoded?

Comment: I just verified and it seems there is always going to be two nested arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var input = "['[\"~:bbl:P5085\",\"~:cosco:NoTag\"]']";

var BBLs_List = JArray.Parse(input)
                      .SelectMany(m => JArray.Parse(m.ToString()))
                      .Select(s => s.ToString().Split(":"))
                      .Where(w => w[1] == "bbl")
                      .Select(s => s[2])
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I explain in the comments this isn't JSON, except at the top level which is an array with a single string value. That *specific* string could be parsed as a JSON array itself, but its values can't be handled as JSON in any way. They're just strings.

While you could try parsing and splitting that string, it would be a *lot* safer to find the actual specification of that format and write a parser for it. Or find a library for that API.

You could use the following code for parsing, but it's slow, not very readable and based on assumptions that can easily break - what happens if a value contains a colon?

```
foreach(var longString in JArray.Parse(input))
{
   foreach(var smallString in JArray.Parse(longString))
   {
      var values=smallString.Split(":");
      if(values[1]=="bbl")
      {
          return values[2];
      }
   }
}
return null;
```

You could convert that to LINQ, but that would be just as hard to read :

```
var value=JArray.Parse(input)
                .SelectMany(longString=>JArray.Parse(longString))
                .Select(smallString=>smallString.Split(":"))
                .Where(values=>values[1]=="bbl")
                .Select(values=>values[2])
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: my ptions.Type1.Values() is of IEnumerable JToken Type. i guess in answer "input" is string

Comment: Probably. My point is that you can't treat this as just JSON. You need to find out the exact format. What if the top level string contained unexpected characters? What if there are 4 values instead of 3 in the inner string? If I had to do this I'd try to create a custom parser using regular expressions, or a parser library like eg Sprache or Superpower based on the actual syntax. I'd try to find a proper client first though, so I don't have to do all this